# OpenGL flicker only on Windows 8

Tags: opengl, windows-8

I have a Windows application which uses OpenGL in a fairly simple way to render textured images (QUADS) into multiple windows in its client-area.

The application behaves fine on Windows 7, but on Windows 8 it sometimes flickers and shows the background in response to user actions, like a mouse click on a window. To be exact: sometimes when some window is mouse-clicked (not on every mouse click), all windows briefly flicker.

I was looking into possible reasons for this behavior. I tried catching the WM_ERASEBKGND message, but that didn't seem to be the cause. I tried working with different GPU cards (and corresponding drivers), and it happens on all (Nvidia Quadro & ATI Radeon HD). In addition, I made some of the image-windows use GDI for drawing, and indeed - when other windows flicker, these images don't (as well as the menu, button area & status bar).

UPDATE: Since the windows are C# User Controls, I've set the AllPaintingInWmPaint & UserPaint Styles to "true". DoubleBuffer is "false", because setting it "true" causes the flicker to be a lot more frequent.

Bottom line: all windows drawn with OpenGL flicker once in a while, and only them, and only on Win8 (not on Win7).

I would very much appreciate tips for the cause of this. My code follows. I initialize the contexts like this:

```
void InitWindow(HWND *hWnd, HDC *hDC, HGLRC *hRC)
{
    *hDC = GetDC(*hWnd);

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | 
            PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;

    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    // pfd.cRedBits = 8;    
    // pfd.cGreenBits = 8;
    // pfd.cBlueBits = 8;
    pfd.cAlphaBits = 0;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 0;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    int format = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, format, &pfd);

    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}
```

And draw to the screen like this:

```
int Render(HWND hWnd, Raster* raster)
{
    Size RasterSize = raster->GetSize();

    HDC hDC = NULL;
    HGLRC hRC = NULL;

    InitWindow(&hWnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    GLenum raster_pixel_format = GL_BGRA_EXT;
    GLint internal_format = GL_RGBA;

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

    glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_format, 
            RasterSize.width, RasterSize.height,
            0, raster_pixel_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            raster->GetData());

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    RECT wndRect;
    ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &wndRect);
    GLsizei wndWidth = wndRect.right;
    GLsizei wndHeight = wndRect.bottom;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // this is usually stated in window coordinates,
    // but since we know the raster gets its size from 
    // the window - we can use raster coordinates
    glViewport(0, 0, RasterSize.width, RasterSize.height);

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );    

    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

    SwapBuffers(hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: First of all, why are you creating and destroying a render context every time you draw your scene? WGL forbids you from setting the pixel format for a particular HWND's device context more than once, so technically this is invalid behavior. You may be getting away with it because you chose the same pixel format every time, but it still is not valid. I strongly believe that if you do not create and destroy the render context each frame, your issue will disappear.

Comment: Actually, this is a rather simplified code. There's a switch to turn on/off the context caching (with the HWND as a key), which makes InitWindow() only be called once. I usually don't cache these handles because I still have issues with cache invalidation (windows are destroyed too far in the hierarchy), but even switching it on (with no windows destroyed) doesn't help. Again, in Win7, the application runs smoothly without this caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to using a machine with multiple video cards.
Disabling any one card solved it.